# Adobe Flex 4 Tree Treelistdata

Tags: flex4, treelist

Is it possible to find if a treeListData is having a sibling or not. In adobe Flex 4 and actionscript 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could check the `item` property of the `TreeListData` instance inside an `ItemRenderer` and either:

- use `item` as `ITreeDataDescriptor` and check the `hasChildren` property
- use `item` as your custom class and possibly check the length of your `children` collection (depending on your data-model).

**Example code:**

```
protected function dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var node:TreeNode = treeListData as TreeNode;
    if(node != null)
    {
        if(node.children != null && node.children.length > 0)
        {
                hasChildren = true;
                return;
            }
     }

     hasChildren = false;
}
```

Hope this answers your question.